# Capturing information for customers such a referral URL and conversion

Tags: python, flask, statistics, analytics

I was hoping to create my own in-house analytics so I tell my customers how many visits their company page got on my site and which URL they came from. I am coding this in Python (Flask) and I wondered if anyone could tell me what is the standard, or sensible approach to this problem.

I think it might be to have some sort of Redis queue which is triggered when a visitor comes and then this information is added to the database later so the site doesn't seem slow.

Comment: A standard solution for folks wanting to do this (while avoiding Google Analytics) is to go with Matomo (previously known as Piwik). This is open source and can be self-hosted or hosted for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard, and sensible approach is to use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/). If you must roll your own, you have one of two approaches. JavaScript that is executed on every page (like GA) and pulls this kind of info into a DB.  The second approach is parsing log files on the server. [Awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is a good bet for that.